# comparing two date picker fields (advanced custom fields) before saving or updating the post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

hope you're doing well. I'm creating a traveling website for a client. when im adding a new voyage there is some custom fields. let's just focus on departure_time and return_time. one for the date the voyage will be, the other for the date when the voyage end. i want to do a check:
the reutrn_time has to be after the departure time otherwise prevent to user from saving the post or updating it. i had tried every thing but no solution founded. let's go over the possible solutions again and discuss them.

Comment: helloo ?????????

Comment: Are you able to add some of the code you have tried to your question so we can better understand the issue?